# WCF: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException on a client side

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, wcf

I have two tables with one to many relation: 1 user <-> multiple orders

```
public partial class TUser
{
    public TUser()
    {
        this.TOrders = new HashSet<TOrders>();
    }    
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string UserName { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<TOrders> TOrders { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class TOrders
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual TUser TUser { get; set; }
}
```

My WCF:  Pay you attention on a different return ways. I would like to return Json message format. If I'm returning orders from the database - I'm getting exception issue on client side (even this list is not empty). If I'm passing just newly created List<> with Add() method where I initialized new TOrders object by myself(not from DBContext) - no problems.

```
public class ServiceOrders : IServiceOrders
{
    private DBContext entities = new DBContext();

    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<TOrders> GetOrders()
    {

        // I'm getting System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException on a client side
        return entities.TOrders.ToList();          

        // In this case data successfully passed to client
        List<TOrders> list = new List<TOrders>();
        list.Add(new TOrders {  OrderId = 1, OrderNumber = "dffg"});
        return list;                      
    }
}
```

I assume problem can be in Web.config files. Can it be?

Comment: What's the concrete error message incl. stacktrace? Your assumption about web.config may be right. So just it to us :)